# How is this contact us script vulnerable / being manipulated?

Tags: php, spam, contact-form

A client recently got a spam warning from their host.

I think I have pin pointed the issue to an old contact us form.  Simple html on the front end and a simple PHP script on the back end.

```
    if ($_POST['submit'] == "Send"){

    //START SEND MAIL SCRIPT 
    $mail = $_POST['email'];
    $to = "me@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Message from Website Contact Us Form";
    $headers = "From: Contact us Form <webmaster@website.co.uk>";
    $message = "Message from Contact Us Form\n\n";
    $message .= "\nName: " . $_POST['contactname'];
    $message .= "\nEmail: " . $_POST['contactemail'];
    $message .= "\nTelephone: " . $_POST['contactphone'];
    $message .= "\n\n\nMessage:\n" . $_POST['contactmessage'];


        if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {

                header('Location: http://www.website.co.uk/contact-us/?action=success');

        }else{

                header('Location: http://www.webisite.co.uk/contact-us/?action=fail');                          

        }//END IF MAIL

}//END SCRIPT
```

I know the remedies to fix it such as sanitizing post vars properly, using captchas, using a hidden 'honeypot' blank field, js tricks etc etc (I also like the look of this script too http://www.alt-php-faq.com/local/115/)

But to help me understand what was going on I want to know how this script is being manipulated.  A foreign script posting vars to it but how do they send email to anyone apart from
 'me@gmail.com' or if they are forcing cc / bcc fields somehow why do I not get all spam as well??

Thanks

Comment: If you really are using a gmail address, it is probably blocking the spam.

Comment: Where do you use the `$mail` variable? This seems to be the one that's most prone to injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line like this `$message .= "\nName: " . $_POST['contactname'];` can be **dangerous**. 
If `$_POST['contactname']='MegaSteve4 \r\nCc: email1@mail.com, email2@mail.com';` are set, 2 uses will get spam mail.

See carefully. Its appending more headers.  In this case **Cc**. I am not sure if *Cc* is a raw email header. But I hope you get the idea.

Comment: so how can we be cartain that the post data contain only one email address to avoid this? a regex maybe?

Comment: Yeah you can use **RegEx** to validate. :)

Comment: This script (http://www.alt-php-faq.com/local/115/) uses a foreach loop - maybe a couple of milliseconds slower than regex but would work fine. Also does some other nice tricks where the form was submitted from ie same domain and also if there is a user agent set etc etc.  Some of these things can probably be spoofed by bots but the harder it is......

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing any escaping of the post data. That means that this form is vulnerable to [injection attacks](http://www.damonkohler.com/2008/12/email-injection.html).

I couldn't tell you how they did it, but that's probably what happened.